# set img border size from input js+php wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have an input and I want to set a border size for image. Size should be equal to value in input. I've written in functions.php script that creates input and function that takes its value

script:

```
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($url ,'/prod/') !== FALSE) {
    echo "
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( `.woocommerce-product-details__short-description` ).after( `<input  type='number'  class='form-control' name='name' id='name' onchange='ramka_size()' value= '$input_value' placeholder='Размер рамки'>  ` );
});
 
function ramka_size(){
    alert(document.getElementById('name').value);
} 
let ramka = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-product-gallery__image');
for(var i=0; i<ramka.length; i++)ramka[i].style.border='$input_value px';
</script>";
}}
```

I've tried to use this but it wasn't working:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#img').attr('border', $input_value);
 });
```

Edited code:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( `.woocommerce-product-details__short-description` ).after( `<input  type='number'  class='form-control' name='name' id='name' onchange='ramka_size()' value= '' placeholder='Размер рамки'>  ` );
});
 
function ramka_size(){
   document.getElementById('name').value;
} 
</script> 
<style>
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image{border: 2px solid black;} 
 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cript should look like this to work

```
echo "
<script>
function ramka_size(){
    var input = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let ramka = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-product-gallery__image');
    for(var i=0; i<ramka.length; i++){
        ramka[i].style.border= input+'px solid black';
    }
} 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-product-details__short-description').after( \"<input  type='number'  class='form-control' name='name' id='name' onchange='ramka_size()' value='' placeholder='Размер рамки'>  \" );
});
</script>
 ";
```

Comment: I've edited to `for(var i=0; i<ramka.length; i++)ramka[i].style.border= input+'px solid #000';` but it doesnt work

Comment: error `Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined`

Comment: like in my example you have to define it before the loop `var input = document.getElementById('name').value `

Comment: function has to be like this: `function ramka_size(){
let ramka = document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-product-gallery__image');
for(var i=0; i<ramka.length; i++)ramka[i].style.border='100 px solid #000';
   document.getElementById('name').value;
} `?

Comment: I've edeted the code. I just have to give inputed number to styles instead of `2`

Comment: you still had the space between number and px, check my update

Comment: Can you add a slash to the <script> ?